# Windows 7 setup location

Tags: installation, windows-7

We have a computer that came pre-installed with Windows 7; we didn't receive an installation disk for that. How would one create a setup installer disk from a machine which has Windows 7?

Thanks,
Sayan

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just contact the vendor and request the installer media?  Or pay the ~$20 to Microsoft for a copy of the media.

Comment: Yeah, but I just wanted to know whether it's possible to get an installer from the installed O/S.

Comment: Seems more like a superuser question

Answer (score 0):

The built-in backup utility system image option with the following system repair prompt will basically give you a setup disc with the current configuration.

Also, using imaging services like WDS will easily pull a valid image from the computer. Using a Technet subscription all installation images can be downloaded or you can copy someone else's installation media as most Windows 7 setup discs are generic these days and usually include all SKUs.

Generally as an end-user, you want to uninstall the bloatware and then go the system backup route for this, according to anime-paul anyway ^^